# hypergeometric function with special Pochhammer symbol

Tags: hypergeometric-function

What is the relationship between these two hypergeometric functions? Can the following function be written as another function of some hypergeometric functions ?
*$$1F1(a+b,2a,x)$$* and $$1F1(a+b,a,x)$$ Can I convert 'a' to '2a'?

Comment: I haven't an answer. But have a look at the interesting document \url{http://www.fuw.edu.pl/~derezins/hyper-published.pdf} around paragraph (4.9). Maybe Kummer's relationship is a step...

Comment: @ Jean Marie:Unfortunately, I did not see anything in this field.

Comment: Have you had a look at {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Kummer.27s_equation} ?

Comment: Another source again {http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1/17/02/01/}

Comment: I did not find anything related.

Comment: Who else is there to help me?

Comment: How about an example reduction?  For instance, https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.3.E20 can be applied and then the derivative computed.  Of course, repeated application of contiguous relations can force something.  Both lead to series expansions.

Comment: My major question is in link:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3002323/inverse-laplace-of-hypergeometric-confluent-function

Comment: I do not want to derive from this function after this change. I want to get Laplace's reverse. Or 2a converted to a. Or a converted to 2 a. Both should have a coefficient in the Laplace variable.

Comment: Why haven't you said in your initial question plainly the origin of your problem and its link with Laplace Transform ? It would certainly help people to help you. If you mean Laplace transform of a 1F1, it can be expressed using other hypergeometric functions {http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1/22/01/} but I stop there because I am not at all an expert on hypergeometric functions...

Comment: @G Cab: to use the inverse Lpalace transform from hypergeometric confluent function, I need to make Pochhamer symble identical. If you can look at this link:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3002323/inverse-laplace-of-hypergeometric-confluent-function

Answer (score 0):

We have that
$$
{}_1F_1 (a + b,2a,x) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {{{\left( {a + b} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } } \over {\left( {2a} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }}{{x^{\,k} } \over {k!}}} 
$$

where the exponent  overlined is a way to indicate the [Rising Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) or Pochammer symbol.

Now, the denominator equals
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {2a} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} }  = \prod\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,k - 1} {\left( {2a + j} \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \prod\limits_{0\, \le \,2j\, \le \,\left\lfloor {{{k - 1} \over 2}} \right\rfloor  = \left\lceil {{k \over 2}} \right\rceil  - 1} {\left( {2a + 2j} \right)} 
 \prod\limits_{0\, \le \,2j\, \le \,\left\lfloor {{k \over 2}} \right\rfloor  - 1} {\left( {2a + 1 + 2j} \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = 2^{\,k} \prod\limits_{0\, \le \,2j\, \le \,\left\lfloor {{{k - 1} \over 2}} \right\rfloor  = \left\lceil {{k \over 2}} \right\rceil  - 1} {\left( {a + j} \right)} 
 \prod\limits_{0\, \le \,2j\, \le \,\left\lfloor {{k \over 2}} \right\rfloor  - 1} {\left( {a + 1/2 + j} \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = 2^{\,k} a^{\,\overline {\,\left\lceil {{k \over 2}} \right\rceil \,} } \left( {a + 1/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,\left\lfloor {{k \over 2}} \right\rfloor \,} }  \cr} 
$$

or, alternatively
$$
\left( {2a} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} }  = \left( {2a} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k + a - a\,} }  = \left( {2a} \right)^{\,\overline {\, - a\,} } \left( a \right)^{\,\overline {\,k + a\,} } 
$$

In both versions it is not possible to simply relate the above results with $a^{\,\overline {\,k \,} }$.